# How do I signup without login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, plugins, devise

I have an admin user in my application and only admin can create and activate users in this application.

When I create a user, devise made a automatic login for this new user. How I can create a user without automatic login?

Comment: So, you want the admin to be able to create users, but for those users to not be able to login until they are activated?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override **Registration Controller** (see tutorials like [this one](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password) )

Then, looking at the original code (can be found [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) ),  you'll have to edit the `create` part.

**Original one** :

```
  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => redirect_location(resource_name, resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :inactive_signed_up, :reason => resource.inactive_message.to_s if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords(resource)
      respond_with_navigational(resource) { render_with_scope :new }
    end
  end
```

What you're looking for is **deleting** this line `sign_in(resource_name, resource)`

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve:

1. Simply create a user instance, that can then log in
2. Create a new user and notify them their account has been created (i.e. "invite them")

In the first case, simply create a `User` instance with the appropriate information (check which fields you need to complete in the console: they depend on you configuration and the "strategies" you use: confirmable, lockable, etc.)

In the second case, you probably want to check out something like this: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `User` is your model, add a boolean field called `is_active` to the `users` table. Then use method `active?` in the `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  #this method will be used by devise to determine if the user is "active"
  def active? 
    #Allow user to log in if the user is confirmed AND if we are allowing 
    #the user to login
    super and (not self.confirmed_at.nil?) and self.is_active?
  end
end
```

To disable a user from logging in, set the field `is_active` to false in a `before_create` filter in `User` model. Or, set the default value as `false` in the migration.

Set `is_active` to `true` to allow a user to login.